# Nested schema in mongoose.js - can only use array notation?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, schema

I'm in the process of creating a REST API with Node, Restify, and Mongoose. In trying to create my schema, I've done the following in a file called `api.js`:

```
var AddressSchema = new Schema({
    address1: String,
    address2: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    country: String,
    postalCode: String
});

var AccountSchema = new Schema({
    property1: String,
    property2: Number,
    property3: Boolean,
    owner: {
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,
        birthDate: Date,
        ssn: String,
        phoneNumber: String,
        mailingAddress: AddressSchema,
        physicalAddress: AddressSchema
    }
});

var Account = mongoose.model("Account", AccountSchema);
```

I then have various restify server stuff, which uses the mongoose model. When I run this with `node api.js`, I get the following error:

> C:\yadda\scjema.js:362
>       throw new TypeError('Undefined type at `' + path +
>
> TypeError: Undefined type at 'owner.mailingAddress'   Did you try
>   nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.
>       at ...

I updated the schema as so:

```
        mailingAddress: [AddressSchema],
        physicalAddress: [AddressSchema]
```

That now seems to work...however, I am not exactly sure what that implies. I do not want my mailingAddress or physicalAddress to be arrays, I want them to be single objects. I'm confused as to why I cannot simply directly reference a nested schema type like my AddressSchema for nesting objects. The only other alternative is to explicitly embed my address schema within my account schema, which means repeating the same chunk of code multiple times (my account schema is actually quite large, and there are five potential locations where an address may be needed.)

Comment: Did you try `mailingAddress: {AddressSchema}`?

Comment: @remus: That just seems to result in a syntax error.

Comment: Blat. Hrm. Wish I could be of more help, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
var AddressSchema = new Schema({
    address1: String,
    address2: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    country: String,
    postalCode: String
});

var AccountSchema = new Schema({
    property1: String,
    property2: Number,
    property3: Boolean,
    owner: {
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,
        birthDate: Date,
        ssn: String,
        phoneNumber: String,
        mailingAddress: { type: AddressSchema, ref: 'AddressSchema' },
        physicalAddress: { type: AddressSchema, ref: 'AddressSchema' }
    }
});

var Account = mongoose.model("Account", AccountSchema);
```